# Creating Sample Size plots using R

Tags: r

I want to know how to create a sample size (multiple options) plot using R.

a simple sample size calculator command such as the following should calculate the sample size:

```
#simple 4pq/d2 formula method- with multiple options for prevalence and precision

zstar = qnorm(.975) #corresponds to 95% CI
p<-seq(0.5,0.8) #estimated prevalence between 50-80%
np <- length(p) 
E <- seq(0.06,0.08) #absolute precision
nE <- length(power)

samplesize=zstar^2∗p∗(1−p) /E^2
```

Following that, i used the following code to get the graphs showing relationship between estimated prevalence and sample sizes needed for each of the precision curves

```
# obtain sample sizes
samsize <- array(numeric(samplesize ), dim=c(nE,np))

# set up graph
xrange <- range(p)
yrange <- round(range(samsize))
colors <- rainbow(length(nE))
plot(xrange, yrange, type="n",
     xlab="Prevalence",
     ylab="Sample Size (n)" )
```

THIS doesn't seem to work...
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want this plot to look like? With `type="n"` you are explicitly drawing nothing at all. It's unclear to me exactly what you are trying to do here. Also, are you sure code like `seq(0.5,0.8)` is returning what you expect? By default the step of `seq` is 1 so it would just return the first value and that's it.

Comment: There are several errors in your code. For the `samplesize` equation to work `p` and `E` must be the same length. Also there are non-ASCII characters in that statement so you probably pasted the equation from a word processing program, not from a text editor. R cannot understand "∗", only "*" or "−" instead of "-".Your `plot` statement includes ranges where x and y coordinates should be. Also `type="n"` means no plot should be produced!

Comment: Hi. thanks for the help. I have made the advised changes.

Comment: I am now getting the following error

Error in numeric(samplesize) : invalid 'length' argument

Answer (score 0):

Your code might work if you change the increment. I'm assuming you want `p` and `E` to have increments of `0.1` and `0.01` respectively. Try using this in your code :

```
p <- seq(0.5,0.8,by = 0.1)
E <- seq(0.06,0.08,by=0.01)
```